# php class autoloader in the class constructor

Tags: php, spl-autoload-register

My class autoloader doesn't work in the class constructor.

```
public function __construct($place = 'site') {

    define('PLACE', $place);

    $source = ($place == 'site') ? PATH_SITE : PATH_ADMINISTRATOR;

    spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {

        // Load classes here dependent on the place location

    });
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please, define *doesn't work*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you need to use $source inside autoload function. You need to add `use`.

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class)use($source) {

    // Load classes here dependent on the place location

});
```

Examples from manual: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#example-195

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE) in

Comment: @user889349, sorry. Fixed.